# Calling a method from a click event in a router-link inside a component (Vue.js)

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, dom-events

I'm trying to achieve with Vue.js a transition between two components. Each component have a button (`<router-link>`) in order to go to the other component.
Each time, the transition change to 'slide-right' when A->B to 'slide-left' when B->A.
Unfortunately, it goes only in one way, the one I've set as default ('slide-right' in data).
The method is not called from the click event on the `<router-link>` because I've tried to add test button to call the function and it worked.
How can I call a method from a click event on `<router-link>` in a component ?

Here is my HTML file:

```
<div id="app">

    <transition :name="direction">
        <router-view />
    </transition>

</div>

<script type="text/x-template" id="B">
    <section style="position:absolute; width: 100%;height: 100%;">
    (some text)
      <a>
       (Some svg icon)   
       <router-link  v-on:click.native="changeDirection"  to="/">Back to A</router-link>
      </a>
    </section>
```

```
 (Same x-template component for A with a button to change to B)
```

my CSS:

```
.slide-right-enter-active,
.slide-right-leave-active,
.slide-left-enter-active,
.slide-left-leave-active{
    transition: all .8s cubic-bezier(1.0, 0.5, 0.8, 1.0);
}

.slide-left-enter {
    transform: translateX(100%);
}

.slide-left-leave-to {
    transform: translateX(-100%);
}

.slide-right-enter {
    transform: translateX(-100%);
}

.slide-right-leave-to {
    transform: translateX(100%);
}
```

and my JS:

```
const A = {
    template: '#A',

};
const B = {
    template: '#B',
};

Vue.component('A', {
    template: '#A'
})
Vue.component('B', {
    template: '#B'
})

const routes = [
    { path: '', component: A },
    { path: '/Proprietaire', component: B }
]

const router = new VueRouter({
    routes
});

new Vue({
    data: {
        direction: 'slide-right'
    },

    methods: {
        changeDirection: function(event){
            if(this.direction === 'slide-right')
                this.direction = 'slide-left';
            else if(this.direction === 'slide-left')
                this.direction = 'slide-right'

        }
    },

    router
}).$mount('#app');
```

Comment: The best way would be to just have the method in the component rather than the root app instance then you don't need to worry about changing direction, because one will slide left and the other will slide right.